# File system management for C# ASP MVC website using Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to walk the line between a specific question and best practices on a broader subject with this question.  Bottom line, I'm building a potentially scalable website that needs to allow users to create folders (including nested folders), upload files to those folders (or at least maintain the relationship between files, folders, and users), and grant access to folders (files under them really) under his/her control to other users.

My high-level plan is to store folder information (and related/nested folders) and file location information in the database along with user access eligibility. So... folders are essentially virtual and do not represent the file system structure at all. Files would be similar, though I'd obviously have to store an actual file system location.

2 related questions - one fairly specific and the one I will accept an answer based on, and one more conceptual.

I've read some information about hashing file paths - does that make sense with a plan like this, or is it overkill and I could just put uploaded files for every user in a folder based on his user id - then base access on relationships and folder structure maintained in the database?

On a broader scale, I'd appreciate any comments/input as to whether or not my overall concept of managing files and folders is correct in this situation. Obviously I won't have access to Active Directory or tools like that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server 2008 or later why not consider using the Filestream feature in the database to let SQL Server manage the files for you? If you are going to use some non database way of storing the filename information a hash can be fast but may be overkill unless there are a very large number of files involved.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Filestream feature. I'll do some more investigating, Thanks.

Comment: What solution did you implement?

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet, but I think I'm just going to store as files in the file system and store the path in the db. I'm using Entitity Framework and from everything I've seen, EF won't take advantage of the FileStream feature, it will just use varbinary(max). Due to the high likelihood for frequent, larger files being accessed, I think using the file system will provide the best performance. Thank you for your assistance in this matter.